# Movie Poster Not Displaying w/ TheMovieDB

Tags: java, android, themoviedb-api

I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing, but I've been trying to get the most popular movie posters to display in a gridview from themoviedb API utilizing the Picasso library. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 20;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            Picasso.with(mContext).load("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key={APIKEY_HERE}&poster_path&images").into(imageView);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above mentioned API will give popular movie list this..

```
results: [
{
poster_path: "/inVq3FRqcYIRl2la8iZikYYxFNR.jpg",
adult: false,
overview: "life.",
release_date: "2016-02-09",
backdrop_path: "/nbIrDhOtUpdD9HKDBRy02a8VhpV.jpg",
popularity: 91.92864,
vote_count: 3497,
video: false,
vote_average: 7.2
}
]
```

Extract poster_path of which movie image you want to display 
Use the below URL to display image http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/inVq3FRqcYIRl2la8iZikYYxFNR.jpg

You can find the document here http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#reference/configuration/configuration

Comment: Oh, so I can't just say popular/poster_path and with would display the posters?

Comment: No that url not available. I tried that url. Response {status_code: 34}

Answer (score 1):

you have to check that url in picasso it returns the whole data not the image url, try to add the value of poster_path to the right url

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a soultion in 2023,
you need to use this new link: [https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/[posterpath]](https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/%5Bposterpath%5D)